# Why don't my DeviceInformation objects have a System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid property?

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, windows-runtime, cppwinrt

I'm trying to enumerate all devices on the system with C++/WinRT in a desktop app:

```
auto devices = winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync().get();
for (int i = 0; i < devices.Size(); i ++)
{
    auto device = devices.GetAt(i);
    auto props = device.Properties();
    if (props.HasKey(L"System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid")) {
        // Get the GUID and print it
    }
}
```

[This MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/build-a-device-selector) states:

> If you do not specify the DeviceInformationKind, or the method you are using does not provide a DeviceInformationKind parameter, the default kind is DeviceInterface.

And [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties) lists `System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid` as a property for `DeviceInterface`.

However, none of the `DeviceInformation` objects returned by `FindAllAsync` have a `System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid` property. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I missed an important part from the second article:

> You can also use these properties to indicate what information you want returned for each device. That enables you to specify the device information that is returned to your application.

You actually have to specify which properties you want returned. This works:

```
std::vector<winrt::hstring> additionalProperties = {
    L"System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid"
};
auto devices = winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(L"", std::move(additionalProperties)).get();
```